# C# dotnet core 3.0 share data between controller route and service bus listener

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, api, .net-core

I have a dotnet core 3.1 web api application. The app is a gateway to expose various other services that communicate through Service Bus (queues, topics). We're using service bus for asynchronous messaging between services. I dont want any sync communication between gateway and other services.

So, I'm trying to find a way to receive request in controller to for example create a resource and send that command to service bus, then sit and wait.

Meanwhile, service will save command to db and emit event.
Gateway is listening on topic to receive the message and now, somehow, I need to pass this message back to the request in controller that is waiting for this message to finish its own execution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't know if the execution of the handler has finish properly by waiting in the controller (as is in your case) in a straight foward way, but, maybe you can do a work arround.

As you know Service bus has a queue or topic where the listener can get the messages sent. But also it has a DeadLetter, where the wrong messages are queued back if any unhandle exception occurs, any message has an internal Id or also your custom body has an Id that you can use to track it and look for it in boths queue or topics. Maybe this can solve your problem, but this is not efficience at all as this is not the desire functionalities of this kind of service, because, in deed, his function is to let you know that your message has been queued, and then you should follow your execution and handle the message in your service.

Comment: I would have a some sort of timeout while waiting for data from another process that listens for Topic. I was also thinking of some sort of Memory Cache that can be shared between processes.

Comment: Service bus is really fast, it would take less than a sec. But if you process is gonna handle thousens of request you could have it as you say. That second solution I can't think how are you going to implemented but I would love to see it if you finally take that option.

Comment: The request comes from UI to create a building. only one building. so there will be no thousands of messages in service bus.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your resource asynchronously, so don't try to give the appearance of synchronous behavior. Return an HTTP status code 202 from your API request and let the client query for the created resource at a later time.

Comment: UI would like to have an access to resource without needing to query and I dont want to couple my microservices to a synchronous operations.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to find a to hack a solution together, but you're fighting your own architecture. One of the many problems you'll have is that you'll have to store a reference to one specific host, the host that has the request frozen waiting for the result, and target that host for the completion signal. This will complicate scaling and updating the gateway tier, diminishing the benefits you get from an asynchronous architecture. You're going down a road that will quickly lead to reliability and maintenance problems